# Do while loop error

Tags: java, swing, oop, loops

Hey guys I have here a program wherein a user needs to guess the word which is being asked by the program itself. The codes doesn't have syntax errors, but my problem here is that every time you input the correct word that is being asked for, the JOptionPane (ErrorMessage) still appears.

What I want to happen is that, the user can only have 5 trials, once the user entered a wrong word at the last trial given, it should display the correct word that is asked for. And once the user entered the correct word, it should go to the next word. Please help me fix this I'm stuck in here for like 3 hours already. Thank you very much.

```
private void guessedWordActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        int trials = 5;
        boolean tryAgain = true;

        do{

        if (wordLibrary.isCorrect(wordIdx, guessedWord.getText())){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your answer is correct! Guess another word.","", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            getRootPane().setDefaultButton(nextTrial);
            guessedWord.setText("");

            wordIdx = (wordIdx + 1) % wordLibrary.getSize();
            scrambledWord.setText(wordLibrary.getScrambledWord(wordIdx));
            guessedWord.setText("");
            getRootPane().setDefaultButton(guessButton);
            guessedWord.requestFocusInWindow();
            tryAgain = false;
            }
        else if (!wordLibrary.isCorrect(wordIdx, guessedWord.getText())) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your answer " + guessedWord.getText() + " is wrong.\n   Number of trials remaining: " + trials ,
                    "Incorrect Answer", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            trials--;
            guessedWord.setText("");
            tryAgain = true;
        }
        }while(tryAgain && trials > 0);

        guessedWord.requestFocusInWindow();
    }

//This is the isCorrect method
public boolean isCorrect(int idx, String userGuess) {
        return userGuess.equalsIgnoreCase(getWord(idx));
    }
```

Comment: Can we see the code for isCorrect? It might always be returning false.

Comment: I'll put 5 dollars on comparing Strings with == instead of equals()!

Comment: ... or equalsIgnoreCase()...

Comment: You can set a breakpoint in if and else lines then debug? to see if isCorrect function operates well or not?

Comment: @JoeBoyle the code runs well not until I tried to loop it. When you try to delete all of the looping statements it'll run fine.

Answer (score 2):

This is happening in your action performed. When you loop, you're not giving the user any time to enter new information.

Why do you want to loop here? You don't need it. Just check once. If they're wrong change the components and wait for `ActionPerformed` to be called again.

If you want to give a maximum number of trials, then you should use some form non-local variable to store it.

Answer (score 1):

When you first give a wrong answer, guessedWord's text becomes the empty String "", so at the next iteration, it will never be equal to the given word, because the String that you get with `guessedWord.getText()` will now be "".

You need to ask the user for a new word and then get the NEW word!

For example, you could set a private variable `int trials` in your class, initialized with 5 (in your main method) and another one, `boolean tryAgain` initialized with true. Then the above method could be written as:

```
private void guessedWordActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){          

  if (tryAgain && trials > 0) {                                  
    if (wordLibrary.isCorrect(wordIdx, guessedWord.getText())){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your answer is correct! Guess another word.","", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        getRootPane().setDefaultButton(nextTrial);
        guessedWord.setText("");

        wordIdx = (wordIdx + 1) % wordLibrary.getSize();
        scrambledWord.setText(wordLibrary.getScrambledWord(wordIdx));
        guessedWord.setText("");
        getRootPane().setDefaultButton(guessButton);
        guessedWord.requestFocusInWindow();
        tryAgain = false;
    } else {
        trials--;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your answer " + guessedWord.getText() + " is wrong.\n   Number of trials remaining: " + trials ,
                "Incorrect Answer", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);            
        guessedWord.setText("");
        tryAgain = true;
    }

  } else {
      //show "the correct word was..."
  }
  guessedWord.requestFocusInWindow();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but it still don't work. I tried to delete guessedWord.setText(""); and replaced the else if with else statement already

Comment: The main point is that guessedWord.getText() does not get the new text, but always the same. You should put the do while loop at the point when you call the `guessedWordActionPerformed()` method (I guess that is a Listener). `guessedWordActionPerformed()` will be a boolean method and it will be just calling `wordLibrary.isCorrect(wordIdx, guessedWord.getText())`. When it return false 5 times, then the user loses.

Comment: Thanks for your update, when the user entered wrong word it shows the number of trials remaining but it doesn't decrement. I tried to change the outermost if into a `while`statement. Unfortunately, it still doesn't work.

Comment: Are the variables declared inside the class and initialized in the main function? Or perhaps you want to put `trials--;` before the error message.